# add to list via foreach loop Datarow

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I looked over a lot of questions, I can't find the answer I need. Apologize in advance if its duplicate.

I have a function that returns `imageslist` which is a list that should have **each row of the `data.Table` as one element**

```
public IList<string> ImageLoader()
{
    var data_str = new StringBuilder();
    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    SqlHelper db = new SqlHelper();
    data.Tables.Add(
        db.runQuery("SELECT * from Gallery")
    );
    data.Tables[0].TableName = "Images";
    foreach(DataRow row in data.Tables["Images"].Rows)
    {
        data_str.Append(
                row.ItemArray[1]
                + (row.ItemArray[2].ToString().Equals("") ? COMMA + "EMPTY" : COMMA + row.ItemArray[2])
                + (row.ItemArray[3].ToString().Equals("") ? COMMA + "EMPTY" : COMMA + row.ItemArray[2])
                + (row.ItemArray[4].ToString().Equals("") ? COMMA + "EMPTY" : COMMA + row.ItemArray[2])
                + (row.ItemArray[5].ToString().Equals("") ? COMMA + "EMPTY" : COMMA + row.ItemArray[2])
                );
        imagesList.Add(data_str.ToString());
    }
    return imagesList;
}
```

But with this function I get wrong output:

**P.S: I also took out `imagesList.Add(data_str.ToString());` out of foreach loop, in that case the output is fine but it's all in one element.**

**Desired Output:**

Airport,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY

Airport,Terminal,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY

Airport,Terminal,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY

AllStar,Retail,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY

EMPTY,Retail,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY

EMPTY,Retail,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY

EMPTY,Retail,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY

EMPTY,Retail,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY

**MY Output:**

Airport, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY

Airport, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY

Airport, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY

Airport, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAllStar, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY

Airport, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAllStar, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY

Airport, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAllStar, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY

Airport, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAllStar, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY

Airport, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAirport, Terminal, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTYAllStar, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY, Retail, EMPTY, EMPTY, EMPTY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep appending to data_str variable, and then you add it to the list. You should skip the data_str and add the row info directly.

```
public IList<string> ImageLoader()
{
    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    SqlHelper db = new SqlHelper();
    data.Tables.Add(
        db.runQuery("SELECT * from Gallery")
    );
    data.Tables[0].TableName = "Images";
    foreach(DataRow row in data.Tables["Images"].Rows)
    {
        imagesList.Add(row.ItemArray[1]
                + (row.ItemArray[2].ToString().Equals("") ? COMMA + "EMPTY" : COMMA + row.ItemArray[2])
                + (row.ItemArray[3].ToString().Equals("") ? COMMA + "EMPTY" : COMMA + row.ItemArray[2])
                + (row.ItemArray[4].ToString().Equals("") ? COMMA + "EMPTY" : COMMA + row.ItemArray[2])
                + (row.ItemArray[5].ToString().Equals("") ? COMMA + "EMPTY" : COMMA + row.ItemArray[2])
                ));
    }
    return imagesList;
}
```